# HTML5 Drag and Drop - can't set the image to show while dragging

Tags: javascript, html

In my app I have a list of images which I drag and drop on to a canvas.  I am dragging an anchor tag with the title, and the details I need inside the attributes.   This is working great.  I want to show a thumbnail while dragging.  This will not work for me.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnAHv/) that I'm using as a guide.  Based on this, I've got the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" draggable="true" ondragstart="DIA.setDragTarget(event)">The drag test object</a>
```

This calls the following method ( I've traced through it, it is called )

```
this.setDragTarget = function(event)
{
    var dragIcon = document.createElement('img');
    dragIcon.src = 'http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png';
    dragIcon.width = 100;
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragIcon, -10, -10);
}
```

This is obviously copied from the fiddle.  It does not work, it still shows the text element.  But, the fiddle, which I have stripped down to the point of not using the CSS in case something was in there, is working.  I tested it with an anchor tag as well, I see no difference between the fiddle and my code.  Here are all the attributes Chrome shows as being set on the element ( I'm wondering if something here is the issue ? )

```
-webkit-user-drag: element;
-webkit-user-select: none;
border-bottom-color: rgb(66, 139, 202);
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(66, 139, 202);
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: rgb(66, 139, 202);
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: rgb(66, 139, 202);
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(66, 139, 202);
cursor: auto;
display: inline;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
height: auto;
line-height: 20px;
outline-color: rgb(66, 139, 202);
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
text-decoration: none solid rgb(66, 139, 202);
width: auto;
```

In a nutshell, every sample I can find online, works, but none mention any style that would stop this working, and none of them work inside my actual code

Thanks

Comment: Works in Chrome but not in IE. Have a look at vendor prefixes.

Comment: I am using Chrome.  As I said, it works fine for me in the fiddle, but, it does not work inside my page, and I can't work out why.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of any style .Just putting the draggable property will give you the thumbnail effect while dragging.And also the document mode should be in HTML 5 .

Comment: Thanks.  I am using Chrome.  My doctype is HTML5.  I am using a ton of HTML5 'stuff'.  But, the code that works in a dummy page, does not work inside my page, I cannot set the drag image.

Comment: This is workin for me in chrome.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>   
    <body>
        <a href="#" draggable="true" ondragstart="setDragTarget(event)">The drag test object</a>
        <script>
           function setDragTarget(event) {
                var dragIcon = document.createElement('img');
                dragIcon.src = 'http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png';
                dragIcon.width = 100;               
            }    
        </script>   
    </body>  
</html>

Comment: I'm not sure if that is a variation on what I had tried, everything I tried that set the source inside the code, failed.  I will try it, thank you.

Comment: Nope - does not work at all.  What I need is to load images dynamically and have them appear.  Your code works the second time, but not the first.  I tried using the 'onloaded' event on the img, but that makes no difference.

Comment: create the image files onload and try switching the image on drag start<!DOCTYPE  HTML>
<html><body>
<div id="drag-with-image" class="dragdemo" draggable="true">drag me</div>
<script>
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png";
 document.getElementById("drag-with-image").addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);
 }, false);
</script>
</body></html>

Comment: Thanks, but that's precisely what I can't do.  I have 2000 thumbnails I'd have to load so the user could use a handful of them, that's why I want to load them dynamically.  I've tried setting the drag image after the image loads, but once you're outside the dragstart event, it doesn't seem to work....